# Using one keystore for my company diffrent customers?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have a company that develops different android applications for its different customers (each of them are a different company ) but almost all apps subject are same. For example android applications for different car firm companies.

Now, the question is that: Is it recommended that I sign this applications with same key, or for each company that ask an android application I should create a different key-store?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the answer is no.

I had the case, where after I had developed an application with a single keystore for multiple customers, one of them asked for the key, so that they could continue the devlopment in-house. The result was a giant mess. I would not wish that upon anyone.

Seting up different keystores is not that hard, and as I see it, besides the organization advantages, there is no other reasons to sign different apps with the same key, unless you have some elaborate lock-in strategy in mind.

TL;DR - Yes, use a seperate keystore for each one of you client companies.

Answer (score 0):

You can store multiple aliases (with different passwords) into a single keystore. I recommend you to read [Signing Strategies](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies).

Comment: While relevant factors are raised, this appears to be written only from the perspective of in-house development, which is not that of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not find any thing on the link about creating keys by different aliases. Also 'Chris' say that it is not good for my question.Really is it better that I use this solution or is better to create different keys. I myself prefere one key. but want to sure that it be a good way.

Comment: Every time you export an App via Eclipse you need to pick a keystore or create a new one. If you pick an existing one then you'll be able to create a new alias (key) in the next step in the same keystore.

Comment: Thanks 'Jelle' . actually they are just one project on solution. So I can create one key by different aliases. I wanna sure that when they published by different names in the app store and by different companies it is yet a good solution. It is good yet in this way also?